# Align RGB image to Depth Image using Intrinsic and Extrinsic Matrix

Tags: image-processing, kinect, image-registration, color-depth

similar questions are solved many times. However, they generally maps depth coordinates to RGB coordinates, by following the next steps:

1. apply the inverse depth intrinsic matrix to the depth coordinates.
2. rotate and translate the 3d coordinates obtained using the rotation R and T matrixes that maps 3d depth coordinates to 3D RGB coordinates.
3. apply the RGB intrinsic matrix to obtain the image coordinates.

However, I want to do the reverse process. From a RGB coordinates obtain the depth coordinates. Then I can obtain an interpolated value from the depth map based on those coordinates.

The problem is that I don't know how can I define the z coordinate in the RGB image to make everything works.

The process should be:

1. obtain 3D RGB coordinates by applying the camera's inverse intrinsic matrix. How can I set the z coordinates? Should I define and estimated value? Set all the z coordinates to one?
2. rotate and translate the 3D RGB coordinates to the 3d coordinates.
3. apply the depth intrinsic matrix.

If this process cannot be done. How can I map RGB coordinates to depth coordinates instead of the other way around?

Thank you!